# programmatically turn acess point on/off in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-8, network-programming

how to turn wireless on/off programmatically by that I mean doing the same thing as going to metro control panel (in windows 8)  and switch the wireless on/off .

I have search on Google and in here but all I could find was how to enable/disable a connection(programmatically) and how to enable/disable the adapter.

this should be related to Airplane mode but turning it on and off causes the wireless to stop working (behave strangely for something's e.g.: hosted network  )until the driver is disabled->enabled (plus I don't know how to turn on/off Airplane mode programmatically).

-please help tag this question.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @RowlandShaw c++ and c#

Comment: Are you writing a Desktop app or Windows Store-compliant app?

Comment: @BenVoigt A desktop application, but I although intend to right a Windows Store-Compliant counterpart.

Comment: Well, disabling and enabling drivers from the full desktop Win32 API is possible, but I don't think you can do it from inside the Windows Store sandbox.

Comment: @BenVoigt isn't disable/enable != Turn on/off ? and in case it is the same how do I do that ?

Comment: To disable a device, you use the SetupDi family of functions (programmatic access to Device Manager).

Comment: @BenVoigt thank you I found it "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544746(v=vs.85).aspx#ddk_example_30_disable_devices_by_an_id_pattern_tools"

Comment: @ψευδήηχώ: Yes, DevCon is the tool for command-line access to Device Manager (it uses SetupDi functions).  Since the functions are pretty complex, calling DevCon might be the easiest approach.